# Show a single item of sample data in SketchFlow running project

Tags: silverlight, sketchflow

I am building a prototype in SketchFlow using a sample data set. When I run the project I can see lists of values no problem but anywhere I have used details mode to display a single record the running project is blank. The data is displayed within Expression Blend (it picks the first record in the set) - the only thing I can think of is that the binding needs to refer to a specific record but I can't see where to set that.

Comment: If I set up a master-details binding I can click through the individual records - so it's definitely the binding I think. Trouble is I don't want to display the whole list just one record (related to the "user" who has logged in)

Answer (score 1):

I found the example in this tutorial works fine:

http://blogs.msdn.com/canux/archive/2009/06/29/mini-tutorial-blend-3-visual-data-binding.aspx

1. Create your sample data source
2. Click on the 'list' mode button above the data source (in the 'data' tab)
3. Drag field(s) onto a list view for the list selection
4. Click the 'details' mode button above the data source (in the 'data' tab)
5. Drag the other field(s) onto the area where you want to display the details

Voila! it works! Or, at least it works on my box ; )

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found a clunky answer. You can put a linked master control on the page with the relevant default value and then collapse it so it's not visible. Does the job but not particularly elegant.